# Call function outside __main__ function python

Tags: python, program-entry-point

If I want to explain the problem in a simplified way, I have two `A.ipynb` and `B.ipynb` files. In file `B` I call a function from outside of `__main__` in file `A` but I can not access it and give `NameError: name 'do' is not defined` error.
File `A.ipynb`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def do(value):
        print(value)

def func(value):
    do(value)
```

File `B.ipynb`:

```
import import_ipynb
from A import *

func('some text')
```

I want to see 'some text' as output in console when file `B` executed. I think Something like (in any way that can be done):

```
def func(value):
    main().do(value)
```

can solve problem.

Comment: You only define `do` **if** you run the A-file. If you run the B-file, `do` will not be defined. That's the meaning of `if __name__ == "__main__"`.

Comment: So what are you asking? You defined something in the main function in file A, meaning it's only defined when file A's main function runs - meaning if you import file A from file B, that thing won't be defined, since importing a file doesn't run its main function. What are you confused on? When main runs?

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*? How is the code supposed to be used, and what is supposed to happen when it runs?

Comment: The `if` statement that checks the value of `__name__` is not an entry point to the script, like the function named `main` in C or Java. All Python programs start at the top and execute statements in order. Are you sure you even *want* such an `if` statement?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're focusing on `func()` being missing/undefined when it's actually that `do()` is missing or undefined.

Your file B is able to find the definition for `func()` but then it tries to call `do()` which has not been defined, because the `if __name__` clause prevented it.